# Wordpress show multiple post types in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, custom-post-type

I'm creating a Wordpress site were I would like to show "tiles" with content from the site on the front page. These tiles are custom post types from the site like "our services", "consultants", "blog posts" and so on.

I know how to show one custom post type in Wordpress, but the problem is that I need to pull multiple post types in the same loop as I want them to be displayed in a matrix. Another problem is that I need to shuffle all the items in a random order, so that for example not all blogs just show in one place but all objects show after different items in random.

The third problem is that I need to show all items for a certain post type and just the latest for another. For example do I need to show all "our services" tiles, but only a couple of the "blog" tiles.

Is this possible to do, or can you not pull out records in this way using Wordpress?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading up on custom wordpress queries https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

For the first question you just need to specify

```
'post_type' => array( 'tiles', 'consultants', 'post' )
```

for the second question

```
'orderby' => 'rand'
```

so you will have something like

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'tiles', 'consultants', 'post' ),
  'orderby'   => 'rand'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For the third question - I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve with one query.

Answer (score 0):

you can customise the things like this ,

```
  $posttypes = array('post_typ1','post_typ2','post_typ3');
   $randompost_typs = shuffle($posttypes);
  $counter = count($posttypes);
  for($i=0; $i<$counter;$i++) {
       // suppose you want to show all posts from post_type1 then
       if($randompost_typs[$i]=='post_typ1') {
             $posts_per_page = -1;
          } elseif($randompost_typs[$i]=='post_typ2') { // will work for 2nd post type
             $post_per_page = 5; // show 5 posts from this post type
          } else {
              $post_per_page = 3; // show 3 posts from last post type
          }
          // here you will use the WP_Query class from wordpress 
           $args = array(
               'post_type' => $posttypes[$i],
                'orderby'   => 'rand',
                 'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page
                );
           $query = new WP_Query( $args );
           if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
            // all the remaining wp loop content for example
            the_title();
            the_excerpt();
            endwhile;
            else:
             echo 'no posts';
            endif;
       }
```

hope this will help, let me know if it has any issue.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be what I'm looking for! However, the posts are not showing completely randomly, but in in chunks. For example first all post_type1 & then all post_type2. I would like them to be completely shuffled so you get: post_type1, post_type2, post_type3, post_type1. Is this possible?

Comment: Check the updated answer , just use `shuffle()` to the post types array

Comment: The post types are still showing after each other, I would like it to be so that the post types that come after each other in the list are different and not the same

Comment: here is an idea then , save the post data in an array in each loop then randomize that array and then print via 1 more loop